# Arduino software: "request for member 'read11' in 'sensor', which is of non-class type 'DHT()'"

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

Im getting this error message with my arduino code "request for member 'read11' in 'sensor', which is of non-class type 'DHT()'"

```
#include <DHT.h>


#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int greenPin = A0;
DHT sensor();

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2); //16 by 2 character display
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000); //wait a sec (recommended for DHT11)
  sensor.read11(greenPin);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Humidity = ");
  lcd.print(sensor.humidity);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Temp = ");
  lcd.print(sensor.temperature);
}
```

I have downloaded the library it said to download, please help!

I took it from this website btw just to avoid copywright issues:
https://www.hive-rd.com/blog/arduino-dht11-output-lcd-module/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line

```
DHT sensor();
```

the use of parenthesis causes this line to get parsed as a forward declaration of a function `sensor()`, taking no arguments, returning type `DHT`.  What you want is to just define `sensor` as a variable with type `dht` (note:
the tutorial uses lower case.)  The correct syntax would be:

```
#include <dht.h>
/* code */
dht sensor;
```

If you refer to the tutorial you linked, you'll see that's how it appears in the code example.